# Redirect the Page on Page Load using AMPScript

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, cloudpage

I have created a CloudPage for when the user clicks the "YES" CTA button that should be captured and redirect to the URL.

I have done the following and I am able to capture the response and update in the Lead object **but can't redirect to the URL**. Can someone tell me how to redirect to the URL when the page loads?

```
%%[
SET @Id = RequestParameter("Id") 
SET @Response =RequestParameter("Response") 
SET @upload = UpdateSingleSalesforceObject("Lead",@Id,"Consultation_Attended__c",@Response)
]%%

%%[IF @Response =="Yes" THEN ]%%
%%=RedirectTo("www.google.com")=%%
%%[ELSE]%%
%%=RedirectTo("www.yahoo.com")=%%
%%[ENDIF]%%

%%=v(@upload)=%%
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you simply need to redirect straight away without any validation then you were close to the solution -

```
%%[

SET @Id = RequestParameter("Id") 
SET @Response = RequestParameter("Response")
SET @upload = UpdateSingleSalesforceObject("Lead", @Id, "Consultation_Attended__c", @Response)

IF @Response == "Yes" THEN
    Redirect("https://www.google.com")
ELSE
    Redirect("https://www.yahoo.com")
ENDIF

]%%
```

The issue was in 2 points:

1. You need to use [Redirect](https://ampscript.guide/redirect/) AMPscript function because you cannot use the [RedirectTo](https://ampscript.guide/redirectto/) one, since:

   > This function is required when using the `<a>` HTML hyperlink tag in emails when the hypertext reference (`href`) attribute is either an attribute or a variable and the hyperlink is a tracked email link.
2. Also, you got to have full links, including `https://` in the start to not retrieve `Bad Request` response on the page.